# Default save type as Unix in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to save by default Unix format irrespective it is a new file or a existing file on different format.

I want to open a simple windows format file add an extra sentence , when I save I want the file to be saved in default Unix format instead of I am making the eol change explicitly
Is there is a way to do it

Comment: You mean the line endings? `\n` instead of `\r\n`? Why have you taged this as Unix and Unix-utils? You're using Windows aren't you? AFAIK, notepad++ only exists for windows.

Comment: Yes from windows, thanx

Answer (score 6):

Check the "Format" box in *Settings > Preferences > New document / Default directory* for selecting new files' default line endings:

[image]

No clue about how to automatically convert every opened file to a given line-ending style though : /

Answer (score 6):

In Notepad++, you can go to Menu > Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix OSx Format. This should convert the EOL characters.